# unable to find an inherited method for function ‘block’

Tags: r, gpu

I'm new on gpuR and tried out the examples of Charle Determan:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gpuR/vignettes/gpuR.pdf.
When I call the function "block", R gives me back this error:

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :    unable to find an
>   inherited method for function ‘block’ for signature ‘"dgpuMatrix",
>   "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric"’

but I can't find the reason.

Can anyone help me?

Best regards

Comment: Thank you, it was a big help